# Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Getting this error while running the test plan on jmeter.
I have also added mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar file in the lib folder and re-started the jmeter as well after adding the jar file.

Can anyone has solution please?

Comment: what version of java are you using ?

Comment: can you show your jmeter.log ?

Comment: I am using java 8

Answer (score 4):

Looking into [Changes in MySQL Connector/J 5.0.8 (2007-10-09)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/5.1/en/news-5-0-8.html) it appears you are using a 10-years-old driver, it might be the cause of your problem.

1. Download latest available JMeter version ([JMeter 3.3](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-3.3) as of now) - let's start clean
2. Download latest GA release of the [MysQL Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) ([5.1.44](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/5.1/en/news-5-1-44.html) as of now), unpack it somewhere and copy `mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar` file to [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
3. Restart JMeter to pick the .jar up
4. Run your test once again. If there will be failures - update your question with screenshots of the [JDBC Connection Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration), [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) Sampler and *jmeter.log* file contents.

Comment: it's working now, thank you for providing  me all the details.